# Sylow subgroup is normal iff subgroups generated are p-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

For finite group $G$ and Sylow p-subgroup $P$, prove that

$P \unlhd G \iff$ all subgroups generated by elements of order a power of $p$ are p-subgroups of $G$.

$\\\\$

I have no idea how to prove this in either direction, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221275/subgroup-generated-by-sylow-p-subgroups-is-normal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$ part is easy since every $p$-power element of $G$ is in $P$, any subgroup generated by $p$-power elements is contained in $P$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ is again easy. Say there are two Sylow subgroups $P,Q$. Let $S=P\cup Q$. Then $S$ generates a $p$-group containing both $P$ and $Q$. Since $P,Q$ are Sylow, that implies $S=P=Q$ so $P\triangleleft G$.

Answer (score 0):

If [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) is you definition of $p$ subgroup then

$\Rightarrow$

Subgroups generated by elements having order $p^k$ form are subgroups of $P$.

> claim: $P$ is a $p$ group iff $|P|=p^n$

Pf: $\Leftarrow$ is trivial.

Conversely, suppose $\exists q||P|$ then by cauchy's theorem there will be an element of order $q$ in $P$. Contradiction. Hence the claim.

Using that claim we get that those subgroups are $p$ groups.

$\Leftarrow$,

$P$ is normal as it is fixed by each conjugation operation.

Comment: How do you use $P$ being normal when you prove $\Rightarrow$ ?

Comment: Can you clarify? E.g., $S_3$ is generated by elements of order $2$.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry in my proof I assumed $G$ abelian. Let me change my answer.

Comment: Thanks, both @JohnBrevik .

Comment: Thanks, @Levent

Comment: @user152715 No, that's still not right. The definition of a $p$-group is that _all_ elements have order $p$-power. See my example.

Comment: @JohnBrevik if $P$ is a Sylow $p$ subgroup then any other subgroup generated by elements of order a power of $p$ would be a subgroup of $P$ right?[ As $P$ is the unique Sylow subgroup]. So those subgroups of $P$ would be a $p$ subgroup.

Comment: In $S_3$ any Sylow $2$ subgroup is not normal, but Sylow $3$ subgroup is. I think.

Comment: OK, sorry, I see what you are saying.